# Which sections of my firebase (or the other backend) codes shall I hide when I am creating a new repository on GitHub?

Tags: firebase, flutter, github, firebase-security

I am currently using GitHub to push my codes on it and I do not know which sections of my codes shall I hide to avoid misuse by other users.

According to copyright licenses, other users except the owner are not allowed to use some specific codes like APIs and so on. In this regard, I want to be familiar with these regulations on GitHub.

Shall I remove my *google-services.json* files from my firebase apps in the repositories?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHoBk.png)

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule of "pushing sensitive code to Github" is that whatever sensitive information you have on your code, you want to put it inside ".gitIgnore"

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend ):

Answer (score 0):

Generally google-services.json does not contain super sensitive data so it is okay not to include it into gitignore file. Check [this](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/bamCgTDajkw?pli=1) discussion for more detailed info.
And make sure always to not commit sensitive data such as access tokens, IP addresses, API keys, etc.